# Data in same row

Tags: sql

I have a table.

```
ID  Contact_Details   Pref
1   1234567890         A 
1   test@test.com      A
2   1234567891         A
2   test1@test.com     B
```

simple select query will not solve this problem

```
select contact_details as mobile,contact_details as email 
from table 
where pref in (A,B);
```

I want a result like this:

```
ID Mobile      Pref  Email           Pref
1  1234567890   A    test@test.com    A
2  1234567891   A    test@test.com    B
```

Please note that I have different pref for email and mobile and I want that in the output.

Comment: which dbms ? sql server , oracle , mysql ... ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this will work:

```
SELECT Id,
       MAX(CASE WHEN Contact_Details NOT LIKE '%@%' THEN Contact_Details END) as Mobile,
       MAX(CASE WHEN Contact_Details NOT LIKE '%@%' THEN Pref END) as MobilePref,
       MAX(CASE WHEN Contact_Details LIKE '%@%' THEN Contact_Details END) as EMAil,
       MAX(CASE WHEN Contact_Details LIKE '%@%' THEN Pref END) as EMailPref
FROM T
GROUP BY ID
```

Answer (score 4):

You can write:

```
select t1.ID, t1.Contact_Details as Mobile, t1.Pref as PrefMobile,
       t2.Contact_Details as Email, t2.Pref as PrefEmail
from Table t1
inner join Table t2
on t1.ID = t2.ID
where t1.Contact_Details not like '%@%'
and t2.Contact_Details like '%@%'
```

Comment: @Moudiz why not?

Comment: It will work with the given sample data, but won't return rows where either the mobile or the email is missing. You would need a `full join` for that, which in turn requires to move the LIKE condition on the `t2` alias to the `JOIN` condition.

Comment: I didnt notice that the id are not unique. in such way it will work.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I believe both fields are required to enter.

Comment: @Rajesh Glad I could help.

Answer (score 1):

```
    DECLARE @Table TABLE (ID int, [Contact_Details] nvarchar(200), Pref char(1));
    INSERT INTO @Table (ID,[Contact_Details], Pref)
    VALUES 
            (1,'1234567890', 'A') 
           ,(1,'test@test.com', 'A')
           ,(2,'1234567891','A')
           ,(2,'test1@test.com','B');

    WITH Emails
    AS (
    SELECT ID, [Contact_Details], Pref
    FROM 
    @Table
    WHERE CHARINDEX('@',[Contact_Details])>0
    )
    , Mobils
    AS (
    SELECT ID, [Contact_Details], Pref
    FROM 
    @Table
    WHERE CHARINDEX('@',[Contact_Details])<1
    )
    SELECT ISNULL(Mobils.ID,Emails.ID) AS ID, Mobils.[Contact_Details] AS Mobile,Mobils.Pref AS PrefMobile, Emails.[Contact_Details] AS Email,  Emails.Pref AS PrefEmail
    FROM Mobils 
    FULL OUTER JOIN Emails
    ON Mobils.ID=Emails.Id
```

Result of the this query:

```
    ID  Mobile  PrefMobile  Email   PrefEmail
    1   1234567890  A   test@test.com   A
    2   1234567891  A   test1@test.com  B
```

Comment: Product specific answer to a question with no dbms specified. At least tell us which dbms this is for.

Comment: My answer is a solution for MS Sql server 2012+